# Put text Inside Kinetic.Circle

Tags: text, canvas, kineticjs, geometry

I'm trying to put text inside a circle from Kinetic.Circle but i can't find the right answer. I have the following code:

```
var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 30,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 20,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2, 
});

var text = new Kinetic.Text({
    text: 'A',
    fontSize: 10,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    width: 5,
    fill: '#000'
});

layer.add(circle);
layer.add(texto);
stage.add(layer);
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this please?

Comment: you haven't given an x,y position to text and there is a typo... 2nd last line should be `layer.add(text)`

Comment: y wrote it wrong it should be layer.add(text);  you're right but i proove to give x,y inside the circle, there should be another way to do this by not giving the x,y coords.

Comment: found the answer, simple:        layer.add(circle).add(text);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position the text like this so that you dont have to provide the x & y coordinates.

```
text.setX( circle.getX() - text.getWidth()/2 );
text.setY( circle.getY() - text.getHeight()/2 );
```